# Plotting the PMF of the Poission Distribution of Columns from a csv Dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to finish writing a function that uses plt.bar function to plot a pmf of a poisson distribution.

I am a beginner and I don't understand how plt.bar works even after looking at https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-bar-chart

```
def plot_poisson(df, col='open', n_pts=100):
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.bar
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("P(X|\mu)")
plt.title("Poisson PMF")
return ax
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are your data already generated trough Poisson distribution? Or you want to generate Poisson distributed data to plot with a bar chart?

Comment: I want to generate Poisson distributed data to plot

Answer (score 2):

So if I understood correctly, you want to draw `n_pts` numbers from a Poisson distribution whose average number of events per interval is equal to the mean value of your data (from the dataframe column).
And then you want to plot the distibution.

If so, you can do it easily with `numpy`, which provides functions to draw random numbers from distributions. For example, [numpy.random.poisson](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.poisson.html) draws numbers from a Poisson distribution.

It's much easier to use [plt.hist](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) instead of `plt.bar`.
With `bar` you must choose a bin size and the bin positions, count by yourself how many data you have in each bin, and plot the histogram. `plt.hist` does all this for you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_poisson(df, col='open', n_pts=100):
    lm = df[col].mean() #get the mean value of your data
    poisdata = np.random.poisson(lm, n_pts)
    plt.hist(poisdata, density=True, alpha=0.5)
    plt.xlabel("X")
    plt.ylabel("P(X|\mu)")
    plt.title("Poisson PMF")
    plt.show()
```

An example picture produced by this function:

[image]

Comment: I'm getting an assertion error "10 != 100 : Your bar graph doesn't have the correct number patches. Make sure you use the n_pts parameter." I don't understand why as it seems like the n_pts parameter is incorporated. Can you advise?

Comment: No idea. You have to show the full code you are using and include the full traceback. Please, edit your question, or open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 def plot_poisson(df, col='open', n_pts=100):
    pts=np.arange(n_pts)
    fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
    lm = df[col].mean() #get the mean value of your data
    poisdata = np.random.poisson(lm)
    ax.bar(pts,poisdata.pmf(pts))
    ax.set_xlabel("X")
    ax.set_ylabel("P(X|\mu)")
    ax.set_title("Poisson PMF")
    return ax
```